# How can I print this string with backslash

Tags: python, string

**Update for clarification**

I have to replicate the functionality from a server. One of the responses of this old server is the one seen here http://test.muchticket.com/api/?token=carlos&method=ventas&ESP=11, except that the double slashes should be single ones.

**End of update**

**Update No.2 for clarification**

This variable then goes to a dictionary wich is dumped to an HttpResponse with this

```
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data,sort_keys=True), content_type="application/json")
```

I hate my job.

**End of update**

I need to store `'http:\/\/shop.muchticket.com\/'` in a variable. And then save it in a dictionary. I have tried several different methods, but none of them seems to work, here are some examples of what I've tried:

```
url = 'http:\/\/shop.muchticket.com\/'
print url

>> http:\\/\\/shop.muchticket.com\\/
```

With raw

```
url = r'http:\/\/shop.muchticket.com\/'
print url

>> http:\\/\\/shop.muchticket.com\\/
```

With the escape character

```
url = 'http:\\/\\/shop.muchticket.com\\/'
print url

>> http:\\/\\/shop.muchticket.com\\/
```

Raw and escape character

```
url = r'http:\\/\\/shop.muchticket.com\\/'
print url

>> http:\\\\/\\\\/shop.muchticket.com\\\\/
```

Escape character and decode

```
url = 'http:\\/\\/shop.muchticket.com\\/'
print url.decode('string_escape')

>> http:\\/\\/shop.muchticket.com\\/
```

Decode only

```
url = 'http:\/\/shop.muchticket.com\/'
print url.decode('string_escape')

>> http:\\/\\/shop.muchticket.com\\/
```

Comment: Err. have you tried just printing the url as is? `url = 'http://shop.muchticket.com/'
print(url)
output: http://shop.muchticket.com/`

Comment: why you escape the forward slash?

Comment: I'm not escaping the forward slash, I need it like that

Comment: `r'http:\/\/shop.muchticket.com\/'` works for me.

Comment: That returns the string with double backslash, as you can see here http://test.muchticket.com/api/?token=carlos&method=ventas&ESP=11

Comment: I think you need to clarify what you mean by "doesn't work", as you have stated you need to store it with the '\/' format.

Comment: let's simplify. Could you spell (one character at a time) what input do you have? What output do you want (spell it)? How do you get your input -- is it a file on disk, a web resource, a database)? It is enough if you demonstrate it for `u'\u005c\u002f'` Unicode string or `b'\x5c\x2f'` bytestring.

Comment: The input is that string, hardcoded. That variable goes to a dict and then I HttpResponse (Django) that variable as JSON

Comment: @SantiagoQuiroga: "that string" is ambiguous (there are many strings in your question). "hardcoded" -- where? In your Python source?

Comment: Yes, in the source there is
    url = r'http:\/\/shop.muchticket.com\/'
    response_data['url'] = url

Then

return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data,sort_keys=True), content_type="application/json")

That HttpResponse can be seen [here](http://test.muchticket.com/api/?token=carlos&method=ventas&ESP=11), but it should be {... "url": "http:\/\/shop.muchticket.com\/"}

Comment: Forget about json and the web server for a moment. Could you choose one from two alternatives: do you want `'\x2f'` or do you want `'\x5c\x2f'` in the `url`? If it is an url then you should prefer `'\x2f'` or as it is normally written  just `'/'` -- drop the backslash as @Bhargav Rao suggested.

Answer (score 2):

The best way is not to use any escape sequences

```
>>> s =  'http://shop.muchticket.com/'
>>> s
'http://shop.muchticket.com/'
>>> print(s)
http://shop.muchticket.com/
```

Unlike "other" languages, you do not need to escape the forward slash (`/`) in Python!

If you need the forward slash then

```
>>> s =  'http:\/\/shop.muchticket.com\/'
>>> print(s)
http:\/\/shop.muchticket.com\/
```

Note: When you just type `s` in interpreter it gives you the `repr` output and thus you get the escaped forward slash

```
>>> s
'http:\\/\\/shop.muchticket.com\\/'   # Internally stored!!!
>>> print(repr(s))
'http:\\/\\/shop.muchticket.com\\/'
```

Therefore Having a single `\` is enough to store it in a variable.

As [J F S](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28745388/how-can-i-print-this-string-with-backslash/28745419?noredirect=1#comment45775486_28745419) says,

> To avoid ambiguity, either use **raw string** literals or **escape** the
>   backslashes if you want a literal backslash in the string.

Thus your string would be

```
s =  'http:\\/\\/shop.muchticket.com\\/'  # Escape the \ literal
s = r'http:\/\/shop.muchticket.com\/'     # Make it a raw string
```

Comment: I'm not escaping the forward slash, I need it like that

Comment: @SantiagoQuiroga What is your expected output?

Comment: Exactly like this: http:\/\/shop.muchticket.com\/

Comment: @SantiagoQuiroga Then you are perfect `'http:\/\/shop.muchticket.com\/'` is correct! Use it as `print('http:\/\/shop.muchticket.com\/')`, you will get the correct output!. :) Buddy you are *correct* , forget the interpreter output !

Comment: But then why [here](http://test.muchticket.com/api/?token=carlos&method=ventas&ESP=11) they show as double backslahes?

Comment: @SantiagoQuiroga That is what I am telling you, they are internally stored as such. You put them in a variable and then make them the value, you will get the correct output!

Comment: to avoid ambiguity, either use raw string literals or escape the backslashes if you want a literal backslash in the string: `r'\/'`, `'\\/'`.

Answer (score 1):

If you need *two* characters in the string: the backslash (`REVERSE SOLIDUS`) and the forward slash (`SOLIDUS`) then all three *Python string literals* produce the same *string object*:

```
>>> '\/' == r'\/' == '\\/' == '\x5c\x2f'
True
>>> len(r'\/') == 2
True
```

The preferable way to write it is: `r'\/'` or `'\\/'`.

The reason is that the backslash is a special character in a *string literal* (something that you write in Python source code (usually by hand)) if it is followed by certain characters e.g., `'\n'` is a *single* character (newline) and `'\\'` is also a single character (the backslash). But `'\/'` is not an escape sequence and therefore it is *two* characters. To avoid ambiguity, use raw string literals `r'\/'` where the backslash has no special meaning.

The REPL calls `repr` on a string to print it:

```
>>> r'\/'
'\\/'
>>> print r'\/'
\/
>>> print repr(r'\/')
'\\/'
```

`repr()` shows your the Python string literal (how you would write it in a Python source code). `'\\/'` is a two character string, not three. Don't confuse a string literal that is used to create a string and the string object itself.

And to test the understanding:

```
>>> repr(r'\/')
 "'\\\\/'"
```

It shows the representation of the representation of the string.

Comment: Here I have a test site with the variable stored as url = r'http:\/\/shop.muchticket.com\/' but it doesn't show as expected http://test.muchticket.com/api/?token=carlos&method=ventas&ESP=11

Comment: @SantiagoQuiroga: I've updated the answer on the difference between `repr(obj)` and `obj` itself. See if it helps to understand the issue better.

Comment: Good! That's what I am trying to tell the OP!

Answer (score 1):

For Python 2.7.9, ran:

```
url = "http:\/\/shop.muchticket.com\/"
print url
```

With the result of:

```
>> http:\/\/shop.muchticket.com\/
```

What is the version of Python you are using? From [Bhargav Rao's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28745419/4099593), it seems that it should work in Python 3.X as well, so maybe it's a case of some weird imports?